# MATLAB: Write string into Excel

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I am trying to write an array of coefficients into an Excel file under 1 column (A1). Here is my snippet:

```
    filename = 'cheby2coefs.xlsx';

for Order = 1:1 
    fprintf('This is');
    disp(Order);

    [b,a] = cheby2(Order, 20, 300/500);
    disp([b,a]);
    %xlswrite(filename,{'Order ',Order},'A1'); %string
    xlswrite(filename,'b','A1');  %string
    xlswrite(filename,b');
    xlswrite(filename,'a');       %string
    xlswrite(filename,a');
end
```

The output that i aim for is something like this:
[image]

However, my code just keeps creating other sheets. What is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the `xlswrite` lines:

From [`xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) documentation:

> `xlswrite(filename,A,sheet)` writes to the specified worksheet.

That means you are writing string 'b' to sheet 'A1' with `xlswrite(filename,'b','A1');`

> `xlswrite(filename,A)` writes array A to the first worksheet in Excel
>   file, filename, starting at cell A1.

You actually do not need to do anything to start writing at A1. Assuming b is a row vector:

```
xlswrite(filename,b');
```

as you have written, should suffice.

If you want to specify sheet and column you can use

```
xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)
```

---

**Update:** I cannot try this right now but I think it should work.

You can calculate `a` and `b` for every `order` and write them to an xls file like this:

```
r = 1; % row number
str = {'a', 'b'};
order = [1 3 5]; % The orders you want to calculate a and b with
for idx = 1:size(order, 2)
    [b,a] = cheby2(order(idx), 20, 300/500); % I do not know about second 
                                             % and third parameters, you should 
                                             % check them.
    vals = [a; b]; % assuming they are row vectors
    cellName = strcat('A', r);
    orderName = strcat('Order ', order(idx));
    xlswrite(filename, orderName, 1, cellName)
    r = r + 1;
    for jdx=1:2
        cellName = strcat('A', r);
        xlswrite(filename, str{jdx}, 1, cellName);
        r = r + 1;
        cellName = strcat('A', r);
        xlswrite(filename, vals(jdx, :), 1, cellName);
        r = r + size(vals, 2);
    end
end
```

Comment: Where exactly will I put this in my snippet? The contents of [b,a] isn;t even populated yet up to the 63rd iteration

Comment: @Erasmus see if it makes more sense now.

Comment: What element does orderName refer to? The Order variable in my snippet refers to the number of times i have to loop through my for loop, as well as indicating what filter coefficient I am in.

Comment: +1: Haven't tested your logic, but it looks right at first glance.

Comment: @Erasmus I updated to make things clearer. orderName is a string like "Order 1" in your example.

Answer (score 3):

`xlswrite` keeps creating new sheets with every call because you didn't specify the worksheet number.

Instead, try this:

```
%// Write b under column A1 in the 1st worksheet
xlswrite(filename, 'b', 1, 'A1')
xlswrite(filename, b(:), 1, 'A2')
```

It's good practice to make sure that `b` is written as a column by converting it to a column vector first with the `b(:)` syntax.

In addition, if you want to write the next set of coefficients under column `B1`, you can do the following:

```
%// Write a under column B1 in the 1st worksheet
xlswrite(filename, 'a', 1, 'B1')
xlswrite(filename, a(:), 1, 'B2')
```

Note that the passed sheet number remains `1`.

Comment: But what if I want to put all of them into 1 column ala filestrem write in c++? I have editted my post to contain the output

Comment: You can't write is at a stream. xlswrite write data at a given location in the Excel file, and doesn't keep track of any "stream offset". You'll have to do it manually by yourself.

Comment: So it's not possible? Even if say the algorithm goes like 1.) Insert string in cell 2.) Populate succeeding cells3.) Insert string, populate etc?

Comment: You can do it, but as I said -- you'll have to compute the offset (the starting/offset cell) by yourself. HebeleHododo has already implemented such logic for you, check out his answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `xlswrite1` ? You can download the module from here [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10465-xlswrite1)

Here is the complete module :

```
filename = 'cheby2coefs.xlsx';
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
Workbook = invoke(Excel.Workbooks, 'open', filename);
set(Excel,'Visible',1);

temp_text= [{'Text'}];
Location = ['A1:A1'];
sheetname = 'Sheet1';
%%

[status, message] = xlswrite1(ExcelFilename, temp_text, sheetname, Location);
if status == 0,
    errordlg(message.message);
end

invoke(Workbook,'Save');
invoke(Excel,'Quit');
delete(Excel);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There's no need for the extra brackets (`[]`) when you're creating strings or cell arrays... Also, your 'A1:A1' range is actually one cell, so why not write simply 'A1'?