# Exporting non numeric(NCpoly type) data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using [NCSOStools](http://ncsostools.fis.unm.si/Home) for non-commutative computation in MATLAB. I create a matrix that I want to export and save to an Excel file. Here is my code:

```
clear all

clc

syms x

NCvars x

A=[x 2x 3x]
```

Normally I would be able to use the command `xlswrite(filename,A)` and save the matrix `A` to an excel file, but instead I am getting the error:

```
Input data must be a numeric, cell, or logical array.
```

Is there a simply way to save the `NCpoly` matrix `A` to Excel? I do not know if in general it is possible to change the data type to conform with the `xlswrite` command. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to save array of chars and it worked:

```
a = ['a', ' ','b']
xlswrite (test.xls, a)
```

may be, xlswrite does not support symbolic variables.

Comment: I think I need to change the class type from NCpoly to char in this case, but the char function isn't doing it.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378708/matlab-write-string-into-excel

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix `A` is [symbolic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symbolic-objects.html), because this is how you defined `x`. You need to assign a definite value for `A` before passing it to `xlswrite`. This can be achieved either by substituting `x` with a concrete value using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html), or not defining `A` as symbolic in the first place.

As a workaround, you could use `char` to convert the symbolic expressions to a string as follows:

```
C = cell(size(A));
for k = 1:numel(A)
    C{k} = char(A(k));
end
```

For an input of `A = [x, 2 * x, 3 * x]` you should get `C = {'x', '2*x', '3*x'}`. If you want to remove the asterisks (`*`), you could use `strrep`:

```
C = strrep(C, '*', '');
```

You can then pass the cell array of strings `C` to `xlswrite`.

Comment: Actually, after some manipulations, my matrix A is numeric, so I get something like, A=[1 2 3], but MATLAB still considers the class type as NCpoly. So the only way I know to export this data is to call it up on the command window and manually copy and paste to Excel. However, the matrices I am working with are thousands of rows long so this is not a very efficient method.

Comment: @Edison I answer only based on what I see in the code snippet in the question. If you share more details about what you've done, I might be able to revise my answer.

Comment: based on what I have written in my original question, do you know if it is possible to convert the 'x' in symbolic format to a string?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to write the array `['x', '2x' and '3x']` to an Excel sheet?

Comment: @Edison But in the end you wish to obtain an equivalent matrix of strings, right?

Comment: @Edison Well, I know that `char(A)` doesn't do what you want, so let me think about it a little. I think I have a good direction.

Comment: @Edison I have amended my answer, did you try it?